# Dynamic Loading of ASP.NET Control using Handler Not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, httphandler

Trying to dynamically load a user control into an aspx page using a custom handler. I'm following the example from http://blog.ovesens.net/2008/12/dynamically-loading-asp-net-user-controls-with-jquery/

```
public class AjaxUserControlHandler : AjaxControlHandler
{
    public override Control GetControl(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Get the path to the user control
        string path = context.Request.Url.LocalPath;

        using (var page = new Page())
        {
            var viewControl = page.LoadControl(path) as UserControl;
            return viewControl;
        }
    }
}




using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

public class AjaxUserControlHandler : AjaxControlHandler
{
    public override Control GetControl(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Get the path to the user control
        string path = context.Request.Url.LocalPath;

        using (var page = new Page())
        {
            var viewControl = page.LoadControl(path) as UserControl;
            return viewControl;
        }
    }
}



using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

public class AjaxEnabledAttribute :     Attribute
{
    [DefaultValue(RequestMethodSupport.All)]
    public RequestMethodSupport Method { get; set; }
}

public enum RequestMethodSupport
{
    All,
    GET,
    POST
}
```

My Welcome Portlet is

```
    [AjaxEnabled]
    public partial class WelcomePortlet : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

In my Web.Config

```
<httpHandlers>
  <remove verb="*" path ="*.ascx"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*.ascx" type="AjaxUserControlHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

In my aspx page.

```
$("#placeholder").load("Controls/WelcomePortlet.ascx");
```

But the control isnt loaded. I put break points in the AjaxUserControlHandler and AjaxUserControlHandler and the code doesn't get run.

Note: AjaxControlHandler, AjaxEnabledAttribute and AjaxUserControlHanlder are in the App_Code folder and have been marked as Compile instead of Content.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What version of IIS are you using? You also need to configure IIS handler mappings or WebServer section in your Web.config.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515343(v=vs.140).aspx
http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/runtime-extensibility/developing-iis-modules-and-handlers-with-the-net-framework

Comment: IIS7. I followed this part of the recommendation but will try the other in case. "For a handler that services a custom extension in IIS 7.0 running in Integrated mode, only a registration in the handlers element is needed. If you want to keep the registration in the httpHandlers element also, create a validation element in the system.webServer section (if it does not exist) and set its validateIntegratedModeConfiguration attribute to false."   Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am glad that my answer helps you. I am the very newbie. Please, accept and promote up the answer.